# Re-factor jquery function to trigger percentage loader

Tags: jquery

I have recently downloaded the jquery percentage loader plugin and am trying to refactor some code behind the examples to suit what I need. The code that I have which is working triggers off the percentage loader on click of the run-multiple button...

```
$().ready(function() {

    // Multiple loaders

    $("#multiple-loader-container").children().each(function (i) {
        var loader = $(this).percentageLoader({width:225, height:225});

        $("#run-multiple").click(function () {
            var thisLoaderRunning = false;
            var totalValue = (i + 1) * 333.0;
            var value = 0;
            // A function representing a single 'frame' of our animation
            var animateFunc = function() {
                value += 17;    
                if (value > totalValue) {
                    value = totalValue;  
                }
                loader.setProgress(value / totalValue);
                loader.setValue(value.toString() + 'kb');
                if (value < totalValue) {
                    setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
                } else {
                    thisLoaderRunning = false;
                }
            }               
            setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
            return false;
            });
        });
});    
function setProgress(value) {
    var volumeDb = Math.round(-100.0 + value);
    $controllableLoader.setValue(volumeDb + ' db');
}
```

I am trying to change this to work without buttons and to just trigger the percentage loader after 2 seconds of the page loading. I will post what I have tried but I can't quite get it to work. Just looking for some help.

```
var progressBarTimer = null;
var progressBarTimerInterval = 2000;
$().ready(function() {              
    // Multiple loaders     
    $("#multiple-loader-container").children().each(function (i) {
        var loader = $(this).percentageLoader({width:225, height:225});         
            setTimeout(animateLoaders(null,i), progressBarTimerInterval);           
        });
});

function setProgress(value) {
    var volumeDb = Math.round(-100.0 + value);
    $controllableLoader.setValue(volumeDb + ' db');
}

function animateLoaders(value, i) {
    var thisLoaderRunning = false;
    var totalValue = (i + 1) * 333.0;
    var value = 0;
    // A function representing a single 'frame' of our animation
    var animateFunc = function() {
        value += 17;    
        if (value > totalValue) {
            value = totalValue;  
        }
        loader.setProgress(value / totalValue);
        loader.setValue(value.toString() + 'kb');
        if (value < totalValue) {
            setTimeout(animateLoaders, 25);
        } else {
            thisLoaderRunning = false;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(animateLoaders, 25);
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for the tip in the answer. What I did was to change the code to this...

```
$().ready(function() {

// Multiple loaders
$("#multiple-loader-container").children().each(function (i) {
    var loader = $(this).percentageLoader({width:225, height:225});

    var thisLoaderRunning = false;
    var totalValue = (i + 1) * 333.0;
    var value = 0;      
    var animateFunc = function() {
        value += 17;    
        if (value > totalValue) {
            value = totalValue;  
        }
        loader.setProgress(value / totalValue);
        loader.setValue(value.toString() + 'kb');
        if (value < totalValue) {
            setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
        } else {
            thisLoaderRunning = false;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
    });
});

function setProgress(value) {
    var volumeDb = Math.round(-100.0 + value);
    $controllableLoader.setValue(volumeDb + ' db');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `animateLoaders(null,i)`, but calling that function doesn't return another function, it returns a boolean. But the `setTimeout` function requires a function to run as its first parameter.

Try changing your call to `setTimeout` to look like this:

```
$("#multiple-loader-container").children().each(function (i) {
    var loader = $(this).percentageLoader({width:225, height:225});         
    setTimeout(function() { 
        animateLoaders(null,i); 
    }, 
    progressBarTimerInterval);
});
```